# How to extract the correct script out of all the scripts using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently using BS4 to extract some information from a Kickstarter webpage: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/louisalberry/louis-alberry-debut-album-uk-european-tour

The project information is located inside one of the script tags: (pseudo-code)

```
...
<script>...</script>
<script>
window.current_ip = ...
...
window.current_project = "<I want this part>"
</script>
...
```

My current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import html

html_ = urlopen("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/louisalberry/louis-alberry-debut-album-uk-european-tour").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_, 'html.parser')
# why does this not work?
# soup.find('script', re.compile("window.current_project"))

# currently, I'm doing this:
all_string = html.unescape(soup.find_all('script')[4].get_text())
# then some regex here on all_string to extract the current_project information
```

Currently I can get the section I want using indexing `[4]`, but as I am not sure if this is true in general, how can I extract out the text from the correct script tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can gather all the script elements and loop. Access the response object content with requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res = requests.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/louisalberry/louis-alberry-debut-album-uk-european-tour")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.select('script')
scripts = [script for script in scripts]
for script in scripts:
    if 'window.current_project' in script.text:
        print(script)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (Instead of dumping to json, you might be able to print the output instead if wanted, oh yeah and REMEMBER TO CHANGE THE VARIABLES WHERE I SAID "Choose a path" AND "if theres any class add it here"):

```
 from bs4 import BeuatifulSoup
 import requests
 import json

website = requests.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/louisalberry/louis-alberry-debut-album-uk-european-tour")
soup= BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'lxml')
mytext = soup.findAll("script", {"class": "If theres any class add it here, or else delete this part"})
save_path = 'CHOOSE A PATH'
ogname = "kickstarter_text.json"
completename = os.path.join(save_path, ogname)
with open(completename, "w") as output:
    json.dump(listofurls, output)
```